# Cypher - How to get all nodes in a repeated (a)-[:REL1]->(b)-[:REL2]->(c) chain

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to neo4j and cypher and looking at how to model/query my data.

I have a set of goods that can be used in/produced by factories.
I have modeled it as such:

```
(:Factory)-[:PRODUCES]->(:Good)
(:Good)-[:USED_IN]->(:Factory)
```

I would like to find all the factories and goods needed to create a specific target good.

Can I do this in the current way I have modelled my data?
If you have any advise on approaching the model in a different way please let me know!

I wrote an example query and outcome to showcase the situation.
The query can only match requirements 2 levels deep, I was looking at something that can match arbitary levels deep and not be hardcoded like this :)

```
MATCH (targetGood:Good) WHERE targetGood.name = "Fuel"
MATCH (targetGood)<-[:PRODUCES]-(factory:Factory)<-[:USED_IN*0..1]-(requirements)
MATCH (requirements)<-[:PRODUCES*0..1]-(factory2)<-[:USED_IN*0..1]-(requirements2)
MATCH (requirements2)<-[:PRODUCES*0..1]-(factory3)<-[:USED_IN*0..1]-(requirements3)
RETURN targetGood, factory, requirements, factory2, requirements2, factory3, requirements3
```

Output
[image: Result of the query above]

Using neo4j 4.0.0 in case it matters for the answer

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in native cypher. Start with the finished good node and look for all of the paths from that node back through `PRODUCES|USED_IN` relationship types to origin nodes that have no inbound `PRODUCES|USED_IN` relationship type.

```
MATCH path=(targetGood:Good {name: 'Fuel'})<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN*..10]-(origin)
WHERE NOT (origin)<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN]-()
RETURN path
```

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for the response!


With `*10` the query does not work for me, but it works with `*` or with `*..10` 

For example: `MATCH path=(targetGood:Good {name: 'Fuel'})<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN*]-(origin)
RETURN path`

Is the WHERE NOT part needed? I seem to be getting the same results with or without, if a node is the origin then it naturally doesn't have any produces or used in relationships coming to it? Or maybe it relates to the 10 limit you have in your answer?

Comment: yes, of course, haste makes waste pre-coffee moment. I added `..10`. It will look like the same result in the browser but if you instead return `count(path)` you will see many intermediate paths when you remove the `WHERE NOT...` clause.

Comment: Oh nice! I understand now why the where not is needed. I get 6 vs 14 paths, with vs without it. About the `*..10` I also needed to have it at the MATCH line. Also I tried changing the where not to the following, what do you think? `WHERE NOT (origin)<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN]-()` So the whole query I have now is the following: `MATCH path=(targetGood:Good {name: 'Fuel'})<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN*..10]-(origin)
WHERE NOT (origin)<-[:PRODUCES|USED_IN]-()
RETURN path`

Comment: rest assured - the match line is the place for the `..10`. I just have focus issues this am :)